# Using Amazon EC2: IP address working fine, but public DNS not

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns

I just finished setting up my app on `Amazon EC2` using `Nginx` and `gunicorn` When I type in amazon's IP address: [54.218.54.156](http://54.218.54.156), the app shows up fine and dandy, but when I use the public DNS: [ec2-54-218-54-156.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com](http://ec2-54-218-54-156.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com) I get the following message from `Nginx`...

[image]

***My sites-available file looks like this...***

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 54.218.54.156;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/flowershop;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/flowershop/flowershop.sock;
    }
}
```

I am using `django` and doing this within a `virtualenv` How is futher configuration required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of possible issues. The most important thing is to look at your log files for nginx (unlikely in this case b/c nginx appears to be serving fine) and gunicorn/whatever other WSGI/HTTP server you're using.

In your case, I think the issue is that you should replace:

```
server_name 54.218.54.156;
```

with

```
server_name ec2-54-218-54-156.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

basically server_name should usually be the url you're pointing to: www.yourdomain.com for instance.

Comment: Thanks, bruh. That did it!